# How to add Lat/Lon (decimal degree) values in Attribute table field in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, shapefile

I have a point shapefile (WGS 1984, GCS) with some random data points. I want to add the latitude and longitude in attribute field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Maria there's a few methods for doing this and remeber that as you say the data is already in a Geographic Coordinate System (WGS 1984, GCS) called WGS84.

Use a tool which is called the ["Add XY Coordinates" tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-xy-coordinates.htm) you can find this in the Data Management toolbox. The tool adds two fields called "Point X" and "Point Y" and populates them with the coordinate values (*bear in mind the values will be in latitude and longitude as this is a GCS*).

[image: Add XY Coordinates]

Or use the [Calculate Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//005s00000027000000) tool. This is a more manual process of

1. Add a new fields to the attribute table, one for Latitude and one for Longitude.
2. Right click the field header select Calculate Geometry and pick either the Data Frame CRS or Data CRS to append the coorindates.

Use the [Add Geometry Attributes](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm) tool which allows you to append several attributs based on spatial and geometric characteristics.

> Adds new attribute fields to the input features representing the
>   spatial or geometric characteristics and location of each feature,
>   such as length or area and x-, y-, z-, and m-coordinates.

Comment: omg I've been what you might call an ArcGIS power user for years and I always did the "Calculate Geometry" thing. I had no idea this tool existed. Thanks!

Comment: @Wes you should also check out the Add Geometry Attributes tool above the Add XY Coordinates :-) http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-geometry-attributes.htm

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for posts on how to get long lat values.  I had a variation of this problem and discovered a few interesting things in ARCMAP 10.1.  I have point data that is in utm zone 10 NAD83 and I just wanted to dump the points out in Lat Long in degrees minutes and decimal seconds.  I tried the first suggestion to use the add x y coordinates after converting my coordinate system to WGS 1984 and transforming it but still got UTM coordinates in my newly added x and y coordinate fields.  Tried a few different WGS re-projections and the best I got was a x y coordinates system that appeared to be offsets from the prime meridian and the equator in meters...?  In the end I gave up on that approach and tried the recalculate geometry suggestion which worked fine for producing decimal degrees and I didn't have to change my base coordinate system from UTM zone 10...I'm figuring it just did the re projection on the fly.  The only problem I had left is that I wanted my coordinates in degrees minutes and decimal seconds and there is no option for that in Recalculate Geometry UNLESS the new lONG AND LAT fields you add are text field types not numeric like float or double, then Recalculate Geometry gives you a bunch new format options for displaying Degrees minutes and seconds.  It makes sense when you think about it,  as the full geographic notation is not a true numeric value (but decimal degrees is).  Anyway I got my desired output and checked the values by entering them as placemarks in Google earth by lat long and my locations seem identical to those in my arcmap data sets.

Another tip if you are working on a locked down esri enterprise geodatabase and cannot freely add and define new attributes,  is to just to export the layer out to a shape file and then you can easily add your new fields as necessary and then recalculate your lat long values.  In my case I needed to dump them out to a spreadsheet so I exported them from my attribute table in the shape file out to a csv...

Comment: Please, post this as a question and give more details, such values of your coordinates. Community will help you.